# Gulp - throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: angularjs, gulp, minify

`gulp-htmlmin` throwing err like

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: Parse Error: <!-- END PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER
```

This same code work with other project but when I'm running gulp it is throwing error like this. How can I resove this.

here, my gulp file code

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');

//Pages
gulp.task('pages', function () {
    gulp.src(['./src/**/*html'])
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            removeComments: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['pages']);
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed gulp-htmlmin?  $ npm install --save gulp-htmlmin

Comment: yup, I've installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you all for comments and answer.**

I got the solution. I've re-install all node modules (as per `Joe Rushton`'s suggestion) and add `gulp-util` module to track error. I've found `<!-- END PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER` is unfinished comment in HTML file, it should be like  `<!-- END PAGE CONTENT WRAPPER -->`.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is working on other machines it’s usually either:

- One of the gulp dependencies doesn’t work with your version of node. Type node -v into your terminal and compare that with your coworkers. I’d recommend the LTS version of node as it’s the most stable
- Somewhere down the line your node_modules became corrupt. Try deleting the entire node_modules directory and run npm install